# Destroy session on separate page

Tags: php

I have a script I found here: http://phpsnips.com/4/Simple-User-Login#.UsmwRWRDu9O

Its super simple, but i'm trying to logout, and i'm having trouble. I made a separate script:

```
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

but for some reason the session variables wont go away! any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to start the session before you end it:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
?>
```